# Error creating embedded signing envelope

Tags: docusignapi

Is there an account feature that needs to be enabled for embedded signing to work?

I just created a new account and I'm trying to create an embedded signing envelope through the API.  I'm getting the folowing:

```
{
  "errorCode": "ACCOUNT_LACKS_PERMISSIONS",
  "message": "This Account lacks sufficient permissions. In-Session permission required when specifying a captive recipient."
}
```

Comment: How did you create your new account?  Did you create it through the [DocuSign Developer Center](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center), or did you create it through some other means (such as clicking the create account link after completing signing of an envelope)??

Answer (score 0):

These permissions should be on by default, however I have seen some sort of a glitch that makes them not work.  Are you using one of the walkthroughs as a basis for your application?  It'd be interesting to know more about what people are doing in order to get in this state.  In any case you should e-mail / chat w/ DocuSign support and have your demo account ID ready to they can turn it on for you.